# How to create "sparse" multi document unique index in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

ive organization id and email(optional) 
i want to create multidocument unique index for email, as email is optional iam not able to insert two documents with email as null value or a document without email.

ive listed the things which i ve tried

1.`createIndex({ "organizationID":1, "email": 1 },{ sparse:true , unique: true})`;

2.`createIndex({ "organizationID":1, "email": 1 },{ partialFilterExpression:{ email:{ $exist: true } }, unique: true});`

Comment: create `sparse` index only for email field `createIndex({ "email": 1 },{ sparse:true , unique: true})`

Comment: it should be unique based on organization id

Comment: unique sparse index works properly on sigle document, but the problem is with multi document sparse indexing

Answer (score 1):

Just create a non-unique sparse index.

Since you can have multiple non-unique null values, it's impossible to mark this index as unique.

Comment: createIndex({ "email": 1 },{ sparse:true , unique: true}) works